# Electronic Map with Lodging pricing

Tags: hotels, maps

A wedding in Jamaica will be at the booked [Prospect Plantation Villas](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Prospect+Plantation+Villas/@18.4183857,-77.0616229,256m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0xd1973f7b7d44fb8b!2sProspect+Plantation+Villas!8m2!3d18.4183857!4d-77.0616229!3m4!1s0x0:0xd1973f7b7d44fb8b!8m2!3d18.4183857!4d-77.0616229).  Is there a method or web services that map nearby accommodations?  The goal is to be as close as possible (walking distance) to the wedding and understand the cost of the decisions plotted on a map: it would be terrific if the prices were plotted on the map for the target date.  Unfortunately Google maps does not plot the price.

Comment: What about Google Maps itself? Open your link, click on "Nearby" in the menu bar on the left side, and then choose "Hotels".

Comment: I have not tried for your location therefor a comment, booking.com does a map with prices for your selected date or range of dates, it applies most of the filters you set for your search.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you're seeing, but Google Maps shows me hotels and pricing:

[image: Google Maps]

Answer (score 4):

hotels.com will let you search for hotels in that region and sort by proximity to a point of interest.

If you select a hotel and click on the "Show on map" option, it shows all the hotels in that area and you can click on each to show prices. For example:

[image]